# Getting errors in npm installation

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

Getting this error while installing typescript

```
C:\ESAB_Scripting\H5ScriptSDK\Samples>npm install -g TypeScript
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/TypeScript - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'TypeScript@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 Your package name is not valid, because
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jkvaidya\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-24T06_50_04_167Z-debug.log
```

Comment: The name of the TypeScript package is `typescript`. Try `npm install -g typescript`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `npm search <package>` command to make sure the package you want to install existed or not on the npm registry.The name is case-sensitive and must match the name exactly. For more info, see [new-package-moniker-rules](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/168978377570/new-package-moniker-rules)

So you need to install it via `npm install -g typescript`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

> npm i typescript -g